# Use laravel with() method in another to get value

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am currently fetching and display some data from my API with the below code:

**My code**

```
public function getTheUser()
{
return User::where('user_id', '10')
        ->with('position')
        ->get();
}
```

**API display result**

```
[
    {
        id: 10,
        name: Mary,
        gender: Female,
        position: [
            id: 1,
            position: Executive,
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to add `->with(role)` inside `position` to get the below desired results

**Desired result**

```
[
    {
        id: 10,
        name: Mary,
        gender: Female,
        position: [
            id: 1,
            position: Executive,
            role: [
                id: 1,
                role: Manager,
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

I will need your help Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using nested eager loading

```php
public function getTheUser()
{
return User::where('user_id', '10')
        ->with('position.role')
        ->get();
}
```

It is described in more detailed way [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading)

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is you want to retrieve the position's child which can be done using

```
  return User::where('user_id', '10')
        ->with('position','position.role')
        ->get();
```

For more info:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading